# Capturing asynchronous response to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ultimate question is why does my response print to console, but not write to the screen? I've followed the directions to this post: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and I'm executing the callback the way I THINK I should be.

I'm ultimately trying to retrieve the array length (seen in the image here[image]

but all my attempts so far have been undefined or "[object Object]"

```js
function myCallback(result) {
  document.write(result); //prints [object Object]
  console.log(result); //prints all response data to console
}
foo(myCallback);
function foo (callback){
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://' + company + '.teamwork.com/' + action,
  headers: {"Authorization": "BASIC " + window.btoa(key)},
  processData: true,
  data: {},
  dataType: 'json',
 }).done(function(response){

  callback(response);
   })
}
```

Comment: just use `response.todo-items` in your callback

Comment: I tried that too. I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined` message. I'm guessing the hyphen throws it off?

Comment: try this: `callback(response['todo-items'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are sending that object and it has `-` in the name of the property you will need to pass it like this:

```
callback(response['todo-items']);
```

Of course you also can pass the whole response (if you need to check the status) and get it there:

```
callback(response);
```

And:

```
function myCallback(result) {
    document.write(result['todo-items']); //prints todo items
    console.log(result); //prints all response data to console
}
```